# "Uninitialized constant" errors in Hyperstack: models and components cannot be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperstack

This is a weird error, because everything worked fine last week. When I wanted to start the app in development mode today I got multiple "Name Errors" saying that some classes cannot be found.

I have a component file called 'index.rb' with following content:

```rb
class Index < HyperComponent
  render do
    TABLE do
      THEAD do
        TR do
          TD { "ID" }
          # some other TD elements
        end
      end
      TBODY do
        SearchRequest.each do |search_request|
          SearchRequestItem(search_request: search_request)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I suddenly get this error message: `uninitialized constant Index::SearchRequest`.
`SearchRequest` is a model. There is no component `Index::SearchRequest`.
It worked last week, but suddenly this came up.

Any ideas? :)

Thanks in advance

Update:
The first error message I see in the console is:

```
Uncaught $NameError
message: "wrong constant name configuration"
stack: "wrong constant name configuration↵    at module_constructor.TMP_Opal_const_name$B_13 [as $const_name!] (http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/corelib/helpers.self-12819e26a0290805599453b792fbf0f79a851b1f41aec5b8b47882438d7488a6.js?body=1:153:14)↵    at singleton_class_alloc.TMP_Module_const_defined$q_25 [as $const_defined?] (http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/corelib/module.self-5472617930a9290fbc25a43d92197430a9f2f23359e95519f0448e3c43a41193.js?body=1:371:71)↵    at singleton_class_alloc.$$method_missing [as $method_missing] (http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/hyperstack/component/native_library.self-75535a84993c140838a291f5280afa5c8027bc47f30991308163acb8bf6b7159.js?body=1:83:48)↵    at singleton_class_alloc.method_missing_stub [as $configuration] (http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/corelib/runtime.self-a59b72816f596f5bb11f5da568edd0b684eec56ddaff0ae5da9834528996763d.js?body=1:1197:35)↵    at Opal.modules.models/application_record (http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/models/application_record.self-58a416171d848eb64cec39146f35ea6fe61a97c774407ec8af7b6152798886ee.js?body=1:10:133)↵    at Object.Opal.load (http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/corelib/runtime.self-a59b72816f596f5bb11f5da568edd0b684eec56ddaff0ae5da9834528996763d.js?body=1:2192:7)↵    at Object_alloc.Opal.require [as $require] (http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/corelib/runtime.self-a59b72816f596f5bb11f5da568edd0b684eec56ddaff0ae5da9834528996763d.js?body=1:2216:17)↵    at Opal.modules.hyperstack-loader-application (http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/hyperstack-loader-application.self-382c06b870470bd068dbf8a33536e9fdd371413f8b450880cf33e931fafc530c.js?body=1:22:8)↵    at Object.Opal.load (http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/corelib/runtime.self-a59b72816f596f5bb11f5da568edd0b684eec56ddaff0ae5da9834528996763d.js?body=1:2192:7)↵    at http://0.0.0.0:5000/assets/hyperstack-loader.self-55b4fc5e1a9419c2c6574d3d23240bc19ca6c327d2bc43f3d74afaf673c5da68.js?body=1:5:6"
```

Also I see several errors after the above one like those:

```
HyperStack autoloader failed attempting to load Object::ApplicationRecord.  Could be a bug in autoloader

HyperStack autoloader failed attempting to load Object::SearchRequest.  Could be a bug in autoloader

HyperStack autoloader failed attempting to load Object::ApplicationRecord.  Could be a bug in autoloader

HyperStack autoloader failed attempting to load Object::User.  Could be a bug in autoloader

HyperStack autoloader failed attempting to load Object::SearchRequest.  Could be a bug in autoloader

Uncaught $NameErrormessage: "uninitialized constant SearchRequestForm::SearchRequest"name: "SearchRequest"stack: "SearchRequest: uninitialized constant SearchRequestForm::SearchRequest"

HyperStack autoloader failed attempting to load Object::SearchRequest.  Could be a bug in autoloader
```

Comment: The reason it says no `Index::SearchRequest` is just saying that is the starting context.  However it does mean that for some reason your class `SearchRequest` is not getting loaded in the client. Do you see other model classes loaded?  Can you try changing the name of the class to something silly like `SearchRequestBogus` and seeing what happens?

Comment: I would also suggest that you make sure this is the FIRST error in the JS console.  Sometimes weird things happen because of previous errors.  You gotta fix them in order.

Comment: @MitchVanDuyn yes there are some other error messages. I edited my post and added them.